# ArrayList not returning expected data

Tags: java, arraylist

I don't know what I'm doing and would appreciate any help.
I'm reading a text file with the following code:

```
7
10 416-555-6667 Burgess Smith 15
15 905-777-8888 Thomas Patel 10
20 905-111-2222 Morris J. Stevenson 5
25 416-222-3333 Spencer Larson 30
30 416-333-4444 Adams Doe 18
35 905-122-5454 Price Hanks 15
40 905-343-5151 Clement L. Webster 8
private static void fileReader() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    int eId = 0;
    String nme = "";
    String phne = "";
    int yrs = 0;
    String line ="";
    Employee emp = new Employee(eId, nme, phne, yrs);
    File inputfile = new File("Emp.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputfile);
    n = in.nextInt() - 1;
    in.nextLine();
    in.useDelimiter("");
    for (int i=0;i<=n;i++)          
    {
        int l = 0;
        int m = 0;
        int n = 0;
        line = in.nextLine();
        while (Character.isDigit(line.charAt(l)))
        {
            l++;
        }
        m = l + 1;
        while (!Character.isLetter(line.charAt(m)) && !Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(m)))
        {
            m++;
        }
            n = m + 1;
            while (!Character.isDigit(line.charAt(n)))
            {
                n++;
            }
            eId = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, l));
            emp.setEmpId(eId);
            phne = line.substring(l + 1, m - 1);
            emp.setTelephone(phne);
            nme = line.substring(m + 1, n - 1);
            emp.setName(nme);
            yrs = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(n));
            emp.setYears(yrs);
            empArr.add(i, emp);
        }
    in.close();
}
```

class for set and get methods:

```
    public class Employee 
{
      private int empId;
      private String telephone;
      private String name;
      private int yearsOfWork;
      public Employee(int id, String name, String telephone, int yearsOfWork)
   {
     empId = id;
     this.telephone = telephone;
     this.name = name;
     this.yearsOfWork = yearsOfWork;
   }
  public void setEmpId(int id)
  {
    empId = id;
  }
  public void setName(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setTelephone(String telephone)
  {
    this.telephone = telephone;
  }

  public void setYears(int years)
  {
    yearsOfWork = years;
  }

  public int getEmpId()
  {
    return empId;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public String getTelephone()
  {
    return telephone;
  }

  public int getYears()
  {
    return yearsOfWork;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return "ID:" + empId + ", name: " + name + ", phone: " + telephone + ", years of work: " + yearsOfWork + "\n";
  }
```

}

When I call the get method of my ArrayList outside of its for loop, the text at each index is overwritten by the text at the last index.

I think I'm missing some fundamental concept of constructors and objects here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What get method on **what** ArrayList?

Comment: Your hunch is correct, you are missing the emp object creation.  You have to move the emp object creation into the loop.

Comment: Here is an example of my attempted usage: https://pastebin.com/hc6ciN3R

Comment: @Gangadhar Kairi I will try that thanks

Comment: @Gangadhar Kairi that worked, thank you

Comment: I always wondering why people trying to shorten variable names for save just one letter like this: phone -> phne, name -> nme and make them not readable. Do they trying to save memory in this way or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hunch is correct, you are missing the emp object creation. You have to move the emp object creation into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Employee class and getter/setter methods are correctly written.
2. Rewrite your fileReader() method similar to given below : -

   ```
   String line ="";    
   //Declare an Arraylist for an Employee
   List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<Employee>();            
   //Read a file
   File inputfile = new File("Emp.txt file path");    
   Scanner in = new Scanner(inputfile);

   //Reading a number from a first sentence 
   int n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());     

   for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
       // Reading each sentence
       line = in.nextLine();   
       //Parse an Emp id 
       int eId = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2));
       //Parse a phone number  
       String phone = line.substring(3, 14);
       //Parse a name         
       String name = line.split("\\d+")[4];          
       //Parse years
       int years = Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\D+")[4]); 
       //Now create an object by putting all above values in a constructor
       Employee emp1 = new Employee(eId, name, phone, years);
       //Add that object in an arraylist
       employee.add(emp1);
   }

   //As you have overridden toString method, print an arraylist
   System.out.println(emp.toString());   
   //Closing the scanner
   in.close();
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.